# Writing ArcPy code to return total footage of pipe for each material types?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am trying to write a Python script that will return the total footage of pipe for each material type. I got as far as getting the total footage for all of the pipes, I am just not sure where to go from here.

```
Footage = 0

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('Pipe_Mains',['MEASUREDLE', 'MATERIAL']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        Footage += row[0]
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use the summarize (statistics_analysis) tool? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) will keep track of each material.

```
materials = dict()

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('Pipe_Mains',['MEASUREDLE', 'MATERIAL']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[1] in materials:
            materials[row[1]] += row[0]
        else:
            materials[row[1]] = row[0]
```

You can then look up the footage of each material like this

```
materials["PL"]
```

will output the total footage of the material.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This works perfectly, I new to all of this so I am going have to study up on using dictionaries so I can use it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Statistics Analysis](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) like this:

```
arcpy.Statistics_analysis('Pipe_Mains','Pipe_Mains_Stats',"MEASUREDLE SUM", "MATERIAL")
```